# Install of lbdvd hangs

Tags: apt, software-installation, sudo

In Ubuntu 18.04 I was installing lbdvd by running `sudo apt install libdvdcss2 libdvdread4 libdvdnav4`. Ubuntu has been setting it for over an hour hung at this screen

> If you acquired this product in the United States, this EULA is
>   governed       by the laws of the State of Washington.
>                                                                                 If this product was acquired outside the United States, then local
>   laws        may apply.
>                                                                                    Should you have any questions concerning this EULA, or if you desire
>   to        contact Microsoft for any reason, please contact the
>   Microsoft                 subsidiary serving your country, or write:
>   Microsoft Sales Information         Center/One Microsoft Way/Redmond,
>   WA 98052-6399.
>                                                                                    Reference: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fontpack/eula.htm
>
> ```
>                                <Ok>
> ```

cannot get it to continue..

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the dialog is asking you to acknowledge it.  I'd try hitting [tab] to get to the "[Ok]", then hit [enter].

Comment: I tried hitting tab and enter, highlighting the <yes> and hitting enter typing in yes and enter... will not continue I finally terminated and removed the files. tried again and same thing. will try to run again today and see what I can come up with..Thanks.